# Assistance with building an inverted-index

Tags: php, search, search-engine, information-retrieval, inverted-index

It's part of an information retrieval thing I'm doing for school. The plan is to create a hashmap of words using the the first two letters of the word as a key and any words with the two letters saved as a string value. So,

hashmap["ba"] = "bad barley base"

Once I'm done tokenizing a line I take that hashmap, serialize it, and append it to the text file named after the key.

The idea is that if I take my data and spread it over hundreds of files I'll lessen the time it takes to fulfill a search by lessening the density of each file. The problem I am running into is when I'm making 100+ files in each run it happens to choke on creating a few files for whatever reason and so those entries are empty. **Is there any way to make this more efficient? Is it worth continuing this, or should I abandon it?**

I'd like to mention I'm using PHP. The two languages I know relatively intimately are PHP and Java. I chose PHP because the front end will be very simple to do and I will be able to add features like autocompletion/suggested search without a problem. I also see no benefit in using Java. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Would using a database be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to index and select everything on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a single file to get and put the serialized string. I would also use json as the serialization.

**Put the data**

```
$string = "bad barley base";
$data = explode(" ",$string);
$hashmap["ba"] = $data;

$jsonContent = json_encode($hashmap);
file_put_contents("a-z.txt",$jsonContent);
```

**Get the data**

```
$jsonContent = file_get_contents("a-z.txt");
$hashmap = json_decode($jsonContent);

foreach($hashmap as $firstTwoCharacters => $value) {
    if ($firstTwoCharacters == 'ba') {
        $wordCount = count($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am working with a 29mb txt file. You don't think a single file containing json_encode($hashmap) would be inefficient

Comment: You could break up to where each alpha character has it's own file. a.txt, b.txt, c.txt. For searching data yes it would be taxing. You could only write to a-z.txt when an addition happens. It really depends on what you're using the data for?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain the problem you are trying to solve. I'm guessing you are trying to make a full text search engine, but you don't have document ids in your hashmap so I'm not sure how you are using the hashmap to find matching documents.

Assuming you want a full text search engine, I would look into using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the data structure. You should be able to fit everything in it without it growing too large. Nodes that match a word you want to index would contain the ids of the documents containing that word.

Comment: You're absolutely correct in assuming I'm making a full text search engine. I'm taking a look at the trie data structure at the moment and this is so much more efficient than what I'm doing at the moment (which is what I described above). I'm looking to implement this now, thanks!

Comment: go here http://www.ics.uci.edu/~chenli/pubs.html and look at the paper titled Efficient Interactive Fuzzy Keyword Search